Git ssh -T git@github.com suceesful but when I push I get Permission denied (publickey) on Windows
I am attempting to push a git repo to github with ssh. I can authenticate but I cannot push.
I am using a ssh key called ssh_key_test1 and this gets employed when on Powershell when I run ssh -vT git@github.com I get
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-32c28593
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-32c28593
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: eliseodifolco@gmail.com RSA SHA256:5aGyYpSOjqW4y96tfoz1WLe+/7xcQucTM+xaWc865pM agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:AC0Md8NfTa8RrXyKJgQgJItHiyO3tYWjVPkGkQOb0uo
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: eliseodifolco@gmail.com RSA SHA256:5aGyYpSOjqW4y96tfoz1WLe+/7xcQucTM+xaWc865pM agent
debug1: Server accepts key: eliseodifolco@gmail.com RSA SHA256:5aGyYpSOjqW4y96tfoz1WLe+/7xcQucTM+xaWc865pM agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
Learned new hostkey: RSA SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
Learned new hostkey: ECDSA SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
Adding new key for github.com to C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts: ssh-rsa SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
Adding new key for github.com to C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file C:\\Users\\i1B541167/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi eliseodifolco! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4084, received 3632 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17622.1, received 15671.7
debug1: Exit status 1

but then when I try
git push -u origin HEAD:main

I get permission denied
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

running
git remote -v

shows that the relevant origin is picked up
origin  git@github.com:eliseodifolco/api_test.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:eliseodifolco/api_test.git (push)

could it be that the ssh service finds the relevant key only for some commands such as ssh -T git@github.com which is successful?

"…could it be that the ssh service finds the relevant key only for some commands…?" We cannot guess without more info. You need to investigate what ssh git uses (if there are many installed). Show us ~/.ssh/config. Debug with GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git push; found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+debug

I am not sure I can run that command in Windows.
I can't see any config file either in the .ssh folder

In Windows the command should be set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"; git push; set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=

This is what I get OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3 debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: No such host is known

Rather strange error, I do not understand it. :-(
